# Have dynamic html load as if it was in an iframe

Tags: asp.net

I have an ASP.net 4.0 site. Users can save an entire html page into the backend database. What I want to do is load the dynamic content into a div on an existing page in a content area and have a couple of things to happen:

I do not want any of the css to affect anything outside the div, when first trying this out loading of some badly formed html would move images and other divs outside the content area around.

A lot of these html pages use the "base" tag for images and links, I want the base tag respected inside the div.

I have a solution that I am going to try which is just to use an iframe and set its url to another child page that loads the dynamic html into its own page entirely. I am just wondering if there is a better solution.

Comment: I think your iframe approach *is* the standard way.  There's just no good way to prevent loaded HTML from influencing the rest of the page.

Comment: If it's an entire HTML document (including `<!DOCType`, `<head>` and `<body>` for example) then yes `iFrame` is the way to go

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment, if you're storing the entire HTML of the page in question (including `<!DOCTYPE>`, `<head>`, `<body>` etc) then yes, using an `iFrame` is (in my opinion) the best option.

It is almost impossible to stop inherited styling of the "parent page" from affecting "injected" HTML.

The main downside to this, however, is that you have little control over making sure the HTML in the iFrame is displayed at the correct size.  One option would be to use client-side javacript (or jQuery) to work out of the rendered size of the HTML and adjust the iFrame controls height/width accordingly... but I think you might have trouble getting this to work effectively.

Comment: I set this up in an iframe already this morning, it actually works pretty well. I just think it is odd to have to set up a seperate aspx page. I am setting the width to 100% and am probably going to have to use one of the many javascript resize height scripts, which I am not to thrilled about.